# WPF Drop/DropEnter wont fire

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a Grid with 2 columns each have a Images inside. I want to simply drag the left image into the right one.

XAML Content:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Name="ImageSource" Grid.Column="0" Source="Patern_test.jpg" />
    <Image Name="ImageDest" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="200" />
</Grid>
```

CS: Init Images

```
ImageDest.AllowDrop = true;
ImageDest.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(img_dest_Drop);
ImageDest.PreviewDragOver += new DragEventHandler(img_dest_DragOver);

ImageSource.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(img_source_MouseDown);
ImageSource.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(img_source_MouseMove);
ImageSource.PreviewGiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(img_source_GiveFeedBack);
```

Events:

```
private void img_dest_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs arg)
{ Console.Out.WriteLine("Start img_dest_Drop"); }

private void img_dest_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs arg)
{ Console.Out.WriteLine("Start img_dest_DragOver"); }

private void img_source_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs arg)
{ 
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Start img_source_MouseDown"); 
    if (sender is Image)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Start drag image 1");
        Image image = sender as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), ImageSource.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ImageSource, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}

private void img_source_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs arg)
{
    if (arg.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Start img_source_MouseMove");
    }
}

private void img_source_GiveFeedBack(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs arg)
{ Console.Out.WriteLine("Start img_source_GiveFeedBack"); }
```

When I try to perform to drag the ImageSource into ImageDest the output is:

- Start img_source_MouseDown (PreviewMouseDown)
- Start drag image 1 (PreviewMouseDown)
- Start img_source_GiveFeedBack (PreviewGiveFeedback )
- Start img_source_GiveFeedBack (PreviewGiveFeedback )
  ...

When I try to perform the "Drop" behavior on the Grid it gets triggered. May its because the drop event is somehow consumed by the "Grid" and not forwarded to  ImageDest?

Comment: You won't get any events when the Image control has no content.  Not sure what the proper advice would be, perhaps a place-holder image that indicates it is empty.

Comment: Yes, this was the root of all my problems. Thank you.